# EWS: getting past Forefront security trying to access /EWS/Exchange.asmx

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have this app that uses EWS to access mail, using the standard /EWS/Exchange.asmx SOAP endpoint.

One my user's mail servers is protected by Microsoft Forefront, and the initial HTTP request to

```
https://server_name/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

is redirected (HTTP 302) to:

```
https://server_name/
CookieAuth.dll?GetLogon?curl=Z2FEWSZ2FExchange.asmx&reason=0&formdir=3
```

which is an regular HTML page, the point of which, I guess, is to make the user authenticate "manually".

I've not heard about Forefront until today, not sure how to handle it.

- Is this normal behavior for Forefront (i.e. it always redirects the initial HTTP request), or is it triggered by something in my app? For example, user-agent?
- If it's normal, how am I supposed to get past this page and access /EWS/Exchange.asmx?
- If it's triggered by something my app is doing, how can I find out what it is?

My code runs on Android and forms its own XML requests without using any SOAP library. At the transport level, I use Apache HTTP client components. The code works fine with Office 365/Exchange Online, and, according to user reports, "self-hosted" corporate Exchange servers with NTLM.

However, in this case, I'm not even getting an HTTP 401: the HTTP 302 is returned by the very first HTTP roundtrip.

Trying to preemptively authenticate the initial request using Basic authentication didn't make any difference.

The user who reported this issue also mentioned that another EWS based app works, so there must be a solution to it.